# Visual Basic - How do you store variables after closing the console?

Tags: vba, visual-studio, variables, console, storage

I've been facing some problems in one of my coding tasks. The question asks me to "store two usernames and passwords after closing the console. These accounts will represent two users that have already registered."

I was told to create a simple registration system for a practice exam paper. I gave the user the option to register an account, however, (pre-made) registered accounts are not saved after console closure.

Do anyone of you know how to store these variables? It would help me solve a few other problems regarding different tasks.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Or do you ask us to solve your coding tasks? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "coding task" refers to some school related work, so you do not need to consider security questions.

Just write the username ans passwort combination into a text file. Writing to and reading from a text file should be straight forward. A bit more sophisticated would be a database, sqlite is quite easy for this task.
If you get stuck at coding, just post your code here.

Comment: I was able to complete the task.

Comment: I created a registered accounts named 'admin' (I was told I could do that) and gave the user the option to register their account. I was thinking of following a similar method to yours but the task was easier than I thought.